# Numbering Bibliography in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I tried to simplify the codes as much as I could. I have two problems listed below.

a) i want to name the Bibliography (Kaynakça) as Kaynaklar.

b) i want to number the Bibliography in the Table of Contents.

**The result i desire is:**

İçindekiler (Table of Contents)

1. Giriş

1.1. Tez Çalışmasının Amacı

2. Kaynaklar
3. Ekler

Thank you.

**chapter1.tex**

```
\chapter{GİRİŞ}
\section{Tez Çalışmasının Amacı}
Text
```

**chapter3.tex**

```
\chapter{EKLER}
Text of ekler
```

**literature.bib**

```
@article{label,
  title     = {Title},
  author    = {Author},
  journal   = {IEEE Transactions on Geoscience and Remote Sensing},
  number    = {1},
  volume    = {39},
  publisher = {IEEE-INST Electrical Electronics Engineers Inc},
}
```

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,top=30mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tikz}               
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}    
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 


\selectlanguage{turkish}


%****************************************
% BIBLIOGRAPHY

%%% Bibliography line spacing
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}

%........................................


%****************************************
% CHAPTERS
%%% Chapter titles
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\centering\bfseries}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\  \thechapter}
  {2\baselineskip}
  {\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{13mm}{3\baselineskip} 
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{10mm}{1\baselineskip} 

%%% RENAMING CHAPTER TITLES
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase{İÇİNDEKİLER}}%
  \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase{TABLOLAR DİZİNİ}}%
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase{ŞEKİLLER DİZİNİ}}%
  \renewcommand{\bibname}{\MakeUppercase{KAYNAKLAR}}%
}
%........................................



%****************************************
% BEGIN
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}




\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1} 



%%% Automatically generated.
%****************************************
% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{İÇİNDEKİLER} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\MakeUppercase\hfil\bfseries\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
    \vspace*{10mm}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.} 
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{.} 
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecaftersnum}{.} 

\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{1\baselineskip} 
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{4em} 
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{4em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{4em}

\setlength{\cftchapindent}{0em}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{0em}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{0em}



%%% Spacing between items
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{\cftbeforechapskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{\cftbeforechapskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{\cftbeforechapskip}

\begin{singlespace}
\tableofcontents
\end{singlespace}
\clearpage
%........................................

\selectlanguage{turkish}


\pagenumbering{arabic}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}

    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \raggedright \normalfont
    \bfseries\large\thechapter.\ #1
    \par\nobreak\vspace{0 pt}}}
    \makeatother

%****************************************
% CHAPTERS
\include{chapter1}
%........................................


%%% Automatically generated.
%****************************************
% BIBLIOGRAPHY (Kaynaklar)

\nocite{*}
\phantomsection
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{singlespace}
\setlength{\bibsep}{1\itemsep}
\bibliography{literature}
\end{singlespace}

\clearpage
%........................................


%****************************************
% APPENDICES (Ekler)

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
\makeatother

\include{chapter3}
\clearpage
%........................................


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you loading both the `apacite` and the `natbib` package? They’re not mutually compatible.

Comment: Hi, i am very new to understand which packages are compatible each other. Do you have any suggestion for correction the codes and solve the problems? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at package `tocbibind` with option `numbib`. Then you do not have to add the ToC in ToC manuelly. The bibliography is in the turkish part. So you have to use `\addto\captionsturkish` instead `\addto\captionsenglish` for the redefinition of `\bibname`. Package `hyperref` should be loaded last.

Comment: @esdd i will look tocbibind and numbib, thank you. Is the \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} line should be loaded after all \usepackage lines? I understand true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
```

is my answer.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you expand your answer a little bit? Further explanation would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to change the name of the Bibliography (for document classes book and report):

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Your text here}
```

For the document class article you need to use:

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{Your text here}
```

As for the second question, you can add your Bibliography to the table of contents by adding this after the `\phantomsection` of your Bibliography:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
```

Comment: \renewcommand{\bibname}{Your text here} is in my codes. and i add the \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} code. Now, Bibliography text is in the TOC, but the number before the chapter is still not there.

Comment: @volkanyazici It sounds like you want everything to work like normal chapters. You can add the chapter number manually as a quick easy fix.

Comment: How can i add manually?

Comment: @volkanyazici Like this `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{2. Bibliography}`